# ui bootstrap typeahead throwing error

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angular-ui-bootstrap, asp.net-web-api2, angular-ui-typeahead

I am using Angular v1.3.0-beta.17

This is the error: I have no idea what is causing this. Some people say its because the controller is not using promises. Others says that it's the deprecated ng-bind-html-unsafe directive. I have read adding ng-Sanitize fixes this. It doesn't. I read a post saying this latest version of angular fixes the error. I have upgraded to this pre-release and still I get the error. The data is coming back from the Web API but the ui-bootstrap typeahead continues to throw this error and no popup is displayed.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at http://localhost:7812/scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js:9:13395
at L (http://localhost:7812/scripts/angular.min.js:100:156)
at L (http://localhost:7812/scripts/angular.min.js:100:156)
at http://localhost:7812/scripts/angular.min.js:101:321
at g.$eval (http://localhost:7812/scripts/angular.min.js:112:390)
at g.$digest (http://localhost:7812/scripts/angular.min.js:109:503)
at g.$delegate.__proto__.$digest (<anonymous>:844:31)
at g.$apply (http://localhost:7812/scripts/angular.min.js:113:208)
at g.$delegate.__proto__.$apply (<anonymous>:855:30)
at s (http://localhost:7812/scripts/angular.min.js:73:495)
```

typeahead-popup.html

```
<ul class="autocomplete dropdown-menu" ng-style="{display: isOpen()&&'block' || 'none', top: position.top+'px', left: position.left+'px'}">
<li ng-repeat="match in matches" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }" ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index)">
    <typeahead-match index="$index" match="match" query="query" template-url="templateUrl"></typeahead-match>
</li>
```

typeahead-match.html

```
<a tabindex="-1" bind-html-unsafe="match.label | typeaheadHighlight:query"></a>
```

I have found the cause of the error: It was a mistake in the controller code:

```
 $scope.getComplexes = function ($viewValue) {

    return $http.get('http://localhost:7802/api/Complexes/' + $viewValue)

        .then(function ($response) {
            console.log($response);
            angular.forEach($response.data.results, function (item) {
                complexes.push(item.Name);
            });                
        }); 
return complexes;      
};
```

.... should have been

```
 $scope.getComplexes = function ($viewValue) {

    return $http.get('http://localhost:7802/api/Complexes/' + $viewValue)

        .then(function ($response) {
            console.log($response);
            angular.forEach($response.data.results, function (item) {
                complexes.push(item.Name);
            });
            return complexes;
        });       
};
```

Comment: can you setup a plunker???

Comment: Here is a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/HiJeN5nfZ5RTY92eYCxj?p=preview

Comment: So, I got the error fixed, now the dropdown isnt showing. Back to the drawing board...

Comment: no ng-app, ng-controller in the plunker

Comment: Ok - added app.js. Can you not see TestController?

Comment: angular itself is not working on [your plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ysm2Vh11BQ9oxTZbfGux?p=preview) check the fork

Comment: I see that now. Don't know why. I have added angular

Comment: please take effort to make sure that basic 2+2 is working.. cant help without you fixing basic issues and making sure that all basic issues are resolved.